# What is the C# equivalent for the VB function IsObject?

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

In VB6, I can write something like this:

```
Private Sub MyMethod(ByVal someParameter Variant)
    If IsObject(someVariable) Then
        'do stuff
    Else
        'do something else
    End If
End Sub
```

According to [the modern VBA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isobject-function), which I realise aren't necessarily an exact match with their VB6 counterpart, this function behaves as follows:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an identifier represents an object variable.

The docs also remark:

> IsObject is useful only in determining whether a Variant is of VarType vbObject. This could occur if the Variant actually references (or once referenced) an object, or if it contains Nothing.

If I have an equivalent function in C#, which takes a parameter of type `dynamic`, what is the C# equivalent for IsObject?

Comment: C# is statically typed. It should be obvious whether the variable type is an object or not. The value can be tested for null though `if (someVariable != null)`

Comment: It would be interesting to know what `'Do stuff` is - it may be that in the .NET world it's relevant to execute it no matter what `someVariable` is - or that a completely different test is required that only shares a passing resemblance to `IsObject`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point. I was just coming to a similar realisation myself; there is inadequate context in the question to allow a reasonable attempt at an answer. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to an 'Object' in VBA is a reference type. You can use the following methods:

[IsPrimitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_IsPrimitive)

[IsValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_IsValueType)

[IsClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isclass?view=netcore-3.1)

These methods combined together would help you migrate that piece of code you have. Note however, that you need to have a strong understanding of [types in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/) - otherwise you will end up with code doing *less* or *more* than you wanted it to do.

Personally having decades of experience with VB6 and more than a decade in C# I would strongly reconsider my reasons for using these. Unlike in VBA, you extremely rarely need to stray away from a strongly typed syntax, i.e. the one where the at least basic properties of your variables are known in advance, such as whether it's a reference or value type.

Comment: Great, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. In the C# we're having to resort to dynamic as an equivalent for variant where strongly typed replacements are not immediately obvious. I dislike dynamic intensely and refactor the code to be strongly typed wherever possible. Remaining usages of dynamic will eventually go in subsequent sweeps of the code.